# grunt replace by regex match fails in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gruntjs

I have `AngularJs` application that uses `grunt` as a `Task Runner`..
Builds are successful as on local machine as inside docker container.

But the problem is when I run `Jenkins pipeline` it fails.. I found out where it's failing but still can't understand what could be the reason. 
Here's my `Gruntfile.js`

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        ...
        replace: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    patterns: [
                        ...
                        {
                            match: /\btheme\-([a-z]|[0-9]|\w)+\.css\b/gi,
                            replacement: "theme-%theme.name%.css"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    flatten: true,
                    src: ['dist/scripts/settings*.js'],
                    dest: 'dist/scripts'
                }]
            }
        }
        ...
    });

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        ...
        'replace'
    ]);
};
```

Jenkins build just hanging on this part, if I comment out that section it works..

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the `%` signs in the `replacement` value with a backslash. For example: `replacement: "theme-\%theme.name\%.css"`

Comment: Yes but didn't help